# Correct print "If" and "else" in one <td> in jsp without use others libs

Tags: java, html, jsp, if-statement

```
<%-- 
    Document   : resultsQueryFile
    Created on : Dec 12, 2014, 11:05:50 PM
    Author     : Serg Bash
--%>
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Results of search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <table border='1'cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
            <tr>
                <!-- Not used table headers you will can mark as "hidden=''"-->
                <th width="10%">
                    Title:
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    Thumbnail:
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    URL:
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    Type:
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    Description:
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    Keywords:
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    Size:
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    Custom ID:
                </th>
                <th width="10%">
                    Hash:
                </th> 
                <th width="10%">
                    Status:
                </th>                
            </tr> 
            <%Iterator itr;%>
            <% List data= (List)request.getAttribute("data");
                for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext();  ) {
            %>
            <!-- Not used table data you will can mark as "hidden=''"-->
            <tr>
                <td width="10%">
                    <strong><%=itr.next()%></strong>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <% if(itr.next().toString().contains("null")) out.println("File loading...");
                    else out.println(itr.next()); %>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <%=itr.next()%>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <%=itr.next()%>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <%=itr.next()%>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <%=itr.next()%>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <%=itr.next()%>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <%=itr.next()%>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <%=itr.next()%>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <%=itr.next()%>
                </td>
            <tr>
            <%}%>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want print table with some data in one  jsp without use others libs, but this print is not correctly works(data mixed in table), because execute one:if or else. Try solve by fynction,but it is no working good.

Comment: For the title, remember that this is a forum-esque post, not a Google search. Make it a clear sentence, not a jumble of words a search engine would love.

Answer (score 0):

If your condition meets, then this should work:

```
<%if(itr.next() == null){ %>
    File loading...
<%}else{ %>
    <%=itr.next() %>
<%} %>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Want to print only if or only else record. When itr.next()!= null-one record, if itr.next()==null -other record

Comment: Why you were converting itr.next() with toString()? Do you want to do something specific here? If not, then null check on itr.next() (returns Object) would be sufficient to make a proper condition.

Comment: Also, what are you getting in data (List)?

Comment: Yes, i try to find string with specific content. "List"- ArrayList

Comment: And what is that specific content, you also need to add check for that.

Comment: Strings from parsing json